# CMake Error: File /cygdrive/.../src/LLVMBuild.txt does not exist

Tags: windows, cmake, cygwin, llvm, cling

I'm trying to build `cling` on Windows7 following the instructions [here](https://root.cern.ch/cling-build-instructions):

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=[Install Path] ..\src
cmake --build . --config [Release/Debug] --target cling
```

I notice that the compiler cmake is using being `Visual Studio 12 2013` (either with cmake-gui or in cmdline), while I get the following error ([full traceback is here](http://codepad.org/XiZNu3oj)):

```
Constructing LLVMBuild project information
CMake Error: File /cygdrive/e/ABOUT-C++/cling/src/LLVMBuild.txt does not exist.
CMake Error at E:/ABOUT-C++/cling/build/LLVMBuild.cmake:28 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:431 (include)


CMake Error: File /cygdrive/e/ABOUT-C++/cling/src/bindings/LLVMBuild.txt does not exist.
CMake Error at E:/ABOUT-C++/cling/build/LLVMBuild.cmake:30 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:431 (include)
```

Why is the path prefixed with `/cygdrive/e/...` but not `E:/...`? Are those valid paths? (The missing files cmake mention DO exist in the corresponding folder!)

Or is that because `llvm / clang / cling` should be built with `cygwin` on windows, while the compiler `vc12` I'm using by default is incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My bet is that your problem lies in your python. Judging on `D:/cygwin/bin/python2.7.exe` it seems that you use special version of python that prepends `/cygdrive/` all over the place.

Try using official [binary package for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Comment: Exactly! How do you usually tell it by experience? Checking nearest line above where `CMake Error` occurs?

Comment: I've cloned CERN's fork of llvm, `git diff`ed `master` branch with `cling-patches` and found that there were no changes to `LLVMBuild.txt` files, `utils/llvm-build` tool and its CMake wrapper. From this i concluded that the problem is with your setup, read the CMake log throughly and spotted `Found PythonInterp: D:/cygwin/bin/python2.7.exe` line.

Comment: Is the problem solved yet? If yes, please mark the post as solution. If no, please add details.

Comment: @arrowd thx for your help! cmake problem finally solved, yet build clang & cling on windows is not a good idea right now... SEE: https://github.com/vgvassilev/cling/issues/73